# Remove everything after (but not including) 3/4-digit sequences using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have certain addresses in the following format

```
G.DE GOUVEIA 1419 (COMP.CH 99) Y RIVERA
J BELLONI 6366 CASI INSTRUCCIONES
ANTONIO MENDEZ 1290 Y ORTICOECHEA
```

And I want to remove everything in them following but not including the 4-digit numbers (they are at least 3 or 4 digits long)

I can use a regex like

```
\d+3.*
```

to catch everything after (including) the numbers, but I don't know how to make it catch only whatever follows the numbers to delete them but not delete the numbers themselves.

Alternatively, I can use

```
(?<=\d\d\d\d).*
```

to catch everything after 4 characters but it would not work for addresses with 3-digit numbers. If I use only 3 \d's, it wouldn't work for 4-digit numbers.

Additionally, some addresses are in the form

```
ALEJANDRO GALLINAL 1588 BIS Y AV.RIVERA
```

And I do want to keep the `BIS`, so I'd want to remove everything after the `BIS`, isntead of after the numbers.
How do I write that in regex?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The addresses in Spanish, The code I'll eventually use will be C#

Comment: There's a certain amount of creativity that goes in to programming.  One extremely simple solution would be to match up to and including the 3 or 4 digit number, get the position where the match ended, and then take the substring from position 0 through the end of the match, leaving behind everything else.  I mention it because that would work in just about any language, even if the regexp library is of very limited capability.

Comment: Please try something first, this reads as a "do it for me" type question... or in other words, not a real question. See off-topic close vote: "Questions **asking for code** must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it but you want to match upto and including not after.  So just reagange your regex like this. `.*?\d{3,}`

```
    static string test = @"G.DE GOUVEIA 1419 (COMP.CH 99) Y RIVERA";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(test, @".*?\d{3,}").Value);            
    }
```

---

Edit do to comment

if you change the expression to `".*((BIS)|\d{3,})"` it handles both cases.

Comment: This is perfect for the digits question. Doesn't solve the bis one but I can just do an if-contains split to run one regex or the other. I was wondering if there was one way to combine both conditions into one Thanks!

Comment: is it always bis or can it be other characters.

Comment: We only care about bis. When two locales in this country have the same address, one of them is assigned a "bis" address to distinguish them.